# What "font sets" can I access using packages?

Tags: fonts, packages

I roughly know how fonts work in LaTeX but right know, I don't want to mess with the details. What I do want to do is to use:

`\usepackage{[lmodern|palatino|times|...]}`

to get matching sets of fonts. What "font sets" -- like Times for text, Helvetica for captions and Courier for code -- are available this way?

A pre-existing list would be nice but I suppose we could also maintain one here if none exists yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `lmodern`

  - Serif: [Latin Modern](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lmodern/)
  - Sans: [Latin Modern Sans](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lmodernsans/)
  - Typewriter: Latin Modern Mono
- `mathptmx`

  - Serif: [Nimbus](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/nimbus/)
  - Sans: Computer Modern Sans
  - Typewriter: Computer Modern
- `mathpazo`

  - Serif: Palatino
  - Math: MathPazo (matching Palatino)
- `garamond`
- `fourier`

  - Serif: [Utopia Regular](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/utopia/)
  - Math: Fourier (matching Utopia)
- `kpfonts`

  - Serif: Kp-Fonts Roman
  - Sans serif: Kp-Fonts Sans
  - Typewriter: Kp-Fonts Mono
  - Math: Kp-Fonts Math
- `MinionPro` *(requires commercial support files)*

  - Serif: Minion Pro
  - Math: MnSymbol

**Deprecated:**

`palatino`--> `mathpazo`

`times` --> `mathptmx`

Comment: May I guess that you use KOMA-Script and by caption you mean headings? `lmodern` say only redefines the serif, sans serif and typewriter fonts. What a heading or caption looks like is defined elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed, I have changed the labels to the proper terms.

Answer (score 8):

The site you'll probably find useful is this the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). It also has to be mentioned that you could use LuaLaTeX which is probably already included in your TeX distribution and then use [OpenType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) fonts with the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package.

Comment: That's a useful resource and I will bookmark it but it doesn't seem to have a list of "font sets". I'll clarify my question a bit.

Comment: Well, it has a list of fonts, categorized by serif, sans etc. and shows for each font how it can be used (copy-and-paste ready). I don't know what exactly you mean by "font set" but you can use all the type styles a font supports.