# Adding fonts to Latex editor

Tags: texmaker

I was trying to add new font style to tex editors. Can anybody know how can i add new font packages to Texmaker any other latex editor?

Thanks

Comment: Use `XeLaTeX`. Then you'll have access to all TrueType (or OpenType) fonts in your system.

Comment: Oh! did I misunderstand?

Comment: @HarishKumar perhaps it was I who misunderstood... I'm not sure after re-reading the question :)

Comment: Please Clarify Whether you are interested in typesetting a document in different font families using latex packages [What “font sets” can I access using packages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54197/what-font-sets-can-i-access-using-packages/54199#54199) and [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document) or Wish to change the Graphic User Interface(GUI)'s font for the Texmaker editor ?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, Go to `Options` → `Configure Texmaker`. In the window that opens click `editor` tab on the left.

[image]

Here you can change.

> to Texmaker any other latex editor?

Other editors is too broad un less you specify the editor. But this provision is there in all editors.

Comment: Thanks. But i want to add the new fonts which are not in the list.

Comment: @ManojKumar Texmaker will list all your system fonts in that drop down list. If you want to add new fonts, just install them in your system and they will appear in the list.

Comment: `Options` → `Configure Texmaker` is not present in TeXmaker 4.3 for OS X 10.9.

Comment: @SimonShine No idea since I am not on mac.