# Changing the number colours in tikz when using dark theme in texmaker

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker

I'm using the dark theme, and while creating a diagram in the tikz environment. [image]

As you can see, I can hardly see the dark purple numbers... Is there a way to change it to a clearer one?

Comment: Maybe you can change the number colors somewhere in the color list? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159401/ for a screenshot. (I don't have Texmaker myself so I can't test it.)

Comment: @Marijn Many thanks ;)

Comment: @Marijn By the way, when creating a tikz figure, is it possible to compile into a .png figure?

Comment: That is a rather different question :) see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the editing options (see comment from Marijn), change the  Graphic Numbers colours to one you like. I put `#f47bda`, the same as the Graphic Keywords.